# IE strips off parameters from a file URI pasted into an address bar?

Tags: url, internet-explorer, url-parameters

**Question:** How do I stop IE from stripping off parameters from file URI pasted into address bar?

**Description of a problem:** I have a "simpleTest.html" page with only this JS code inside, that returns the current location of the browser:

```
console.log("document.URL: " + document.URL);
console.log("document.location: " + document.location)
console.log("document.location.href: " + document.location.href)
console.log("window.location: " + window.location)
console.log("parent.frames.document.location: " + parent.frames.document.location)
```

When I paste the address to this file in IE's address bar with some parameters, for instance:

```
file:///pathToFile/simpleTest.html?dupa=2
```

The link gets changed to:

```
file:///pathToFile/simpleTest.html
```

When I paste it for the 2nd time the parameters will stay there. If however in the meantime I access some other resources, I will have to paste it 2 more consecutive times for the parameters to remain.

Moreover, after I've place the website in my local Apache and access it through HTTP, the parameters remained:

```
http://127.0.0.1/pathToFile/simpleTest.html?dupa=2
```

It works fine for FF and Chrome, for both file and http protocols. Any ideas about this strange behavior in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[file:///](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will open a file on your drive or network drive using the OS. When using `http://` you're telling the browser that this is a hypertext link to a file located on the Internet, not locally.

You're likely seeing the parameters after several tries because IE is just saving your history.

Also, having a `?` in the URL implies you have some server-side scripting involved to process the URL parameter(s), which would not run unless through a web server.

Comment: Any idea how I could force IE to use browser engine instead of OS with a file protocol?

Comment: I'm afraid that's handled at the system-level (like calling 'system' in a program), so outside a user's control :-/   I coded a product with an HTTP server built in and had a similar problem...the only solution was to send the file via HTTP, which albeit is slower.

Comment: One alternative is to use anchors with `#` instead of `?`. That way it won't be removed, and you can still access it with JavaScript.

Comment: Even the anchor part does not pass to (my) IE8. What could be holding it back?